# Paperclip advanced routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, paperclip

I have a problem with paperclip and routes.

**app/models/emoji.rb**

```
class Emoji
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :frames
end
```

**app/models/frame.rb**

```
class Frame

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  has_mongoid_attached_file :source_image, styles: {
                               px8: { geometry: '8x8#',     format: 'png'},
                               px16: { geometry: '16x16#',   format: 'png'},
                               px32: { geometry: '32x32#',   format: 'png'},
                               px64: { geometry: '64x64#',   format: 'png'},
                               px128: { geometry: '128x128#', format: 'png'}
                            }

  belongs_to :emoji

end
```

**I want to have routes like:**

emoji/#emoji_name.png

emoji/#emoji_name.png?size=#size_name

emoji/#emoji_name/frames/#number.png

emoji/#emoji_name/frames/#nember.png?size=#size_name

These routes should display the corresponding png image.

Cheers, 
Vassil Kalkov

Comment: So what is your specific problem?

Comment: Don't know how to implement that :)